# Link causes double border

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, border

Hez guys, I have some elements on page, which I've wrapped with border. The elements are close to each other so of course, on the place, where they touch each other, I've got double border.

Think is, I've made links from these elements, so now, some additional border is applyed and I don't know how to remove it.

Code below usefully removed double border when element's we're not links.

Can you please help me to remove this border which comes from link ?

Thank you}

HTML

```
    <section class="popular-items clearfix">
        <a href="detail.html">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/pink.png" alt="pink"><br>
                <span>2015</span>
                <h4 class="pink">pink</h4>
                <p class="out-of-stock">Abc</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="detail.html">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/white.png" alt="white"><br>
                <h4 class="green">white</h4>
                <p>5 €</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="detail.html">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/pink.png" alt="pink"><br>
                <h4 class="pink">Pink</h4>
                <p class="coming-soon">Pink</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="detail.html">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/red.png" alt="red"><br>
                <h4 class="red">Red</h4>
                <p>5 €</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </section>
```

SCSS

```
.popular-items {
    width: 100%;

    .item {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 1%;
    border-right-width: 0;
    height: 420px;

        &:last-child {
        border-right-width: 1px;
    }

        &:hover + & {
        border-left-width: 0;
    }

        &:hover {
        border: 1px $dark solid;
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: So you want to remove all border from bottom or only from link?

Comment: Only from link, so I will get nice 1px border on every element

Comment: but in your example in every element there is 1px border but not double.

Comment: Yes, that's the think. But these elements are close to each other, so propably this cause 2px border on places, where they touching each other. I need to get rid of this

Comment: check this..it is what i am getting https://jsfiddle.net/w3vrd4kL/

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any border there

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you can fix that by setting the border of the links to 0px.

```
border : none;
```